# Shopify API returns 401 Unauthorised - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I've created shopify partner app. App was succesfully connected with shop. After that I created webhook on 'orders/updated'. Following code is in webhook callback, but Shopify API returns 401 Unauzhorized.

```
url = request.headers['x-shopify-shop-domain'] # shop url
token = request.filtered_parameters["token"] # token from header
session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(url, token) # create session
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
shop = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current # returns 401 Unauthorized
```

The error is following:

```
ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess (Failed.  Response code = 401.  Response message = Unauthorized.)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you skipped the whole part about authenticating the webhook. To ensure you don't get hammered by junk, you need to take the steps outlined here with your incoming data: https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/webhooks#verify-webhook

Comment: Verification checks authenticity off data in webhook using SHARED_SECRET. I couldn't find SHARED_SECRET in my dashboard

Comment: That's just your secret API key

Comment: I've already tried to use secret key as a second argument to ShopifyAPI::Session.new(url, sk)
but I got same error.

Comment: The documentation makes it pretty clear how to valiidate webhooks. Follow the recipe and you will have success.